# Putting CPU and Memory Management model all together

Tags: c, assembly, memory, operating-system, malloc

**WARNING**: This is long but I hope it can be useful for people like me in the future.

I think I know what program counter is, how lazy memory allocation works, what MMU does, how virtual memory address is mapped to physical address and the purpose of L1, L2 caches. What I really have trouble with is is how they all fit together in a high level when we run a C code.

Suppose I have this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int* ptr;
    int n = 1000000, i = 0;

    // Dynamically allocate memory using malloc()
    ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    ptr[0] = 99;
    i += 100;
    printf("%d\n", ptr[0]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

So here is my attempt to put everything together:

1. After `execve()` is called, part of the executable is loaded into the memory, e.g. text and data segment, but most of the code are not - they are loaded on demand (demand paging).
2. The address of the first instruction is in the process table's program counter (PC) field as well as physically in the PC register, ready to be used.
3. As the CPU executes instructions, PC is updated (usually +1, but jump can go to a different address).
4. Enter the main function: `ptr`, `n`, and `i` are in the stack.
5. Next, when we call `malloc`, the C library will ask the OS (I think via `sbrk()` sys call, or is it `mmap()`?) to allocate some memory on the heap.
6. `malloc` succeeds in this case, returning a virtual memory address (VMA), but the physically memory may not have been allocated yet. The page table doesn't contain the VMA, so when CPU tries to access such VMA, a page fault will be generated.
7. In our case, when we do `ptr[0] = 99`, CPU raises a page fault. I am not sure if the entire array is allocated or just the first page (4k size) though.

But now I don't know how to put cache access into the picture. How does `i` put into L1 cache? How does it relate to VMA?

Sorry if this is confusing. I just hope someone could help walk me through the entire process...

Comment: Yeah you got those steps about right. The OS does not know your array size, so the page fault only brings in that page (although it could optimize by prefetching). Cache just duplicates main memory content for faster access. It has no user visible address.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it @Jester. Could you clarify "doesn't know array size, so brings in that page"? Which page is it exactly, sorry. Also, I guess I am lost trying to figure out the order of data access. I got a VM address, i want to load the value of `i`. How does CPU know `i`"'s value is stored in the cache at this address? Is there a TLB in the L1 cache too?

Comment: The page that contains the address that was accessed, meaning `ptr[0]`. The cache lines have so called tags which store the high order bits of the address so the cpu knows the mapping. See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)

Comment: Caches are an optimisation. Their management can become complex but in their simpler form, the L1 and L2 are just two warehouses where "all" mem accesses "must" go through. If the CPU finds what it need in such warehouses it doesn't go as far as into memory. Caches are independent of paging, they affects "everything" that goes to mem. Of course without an architecture tag it's impossible to be totally correct (in fact my statements are grossly oversimplified). CPU designers get very creative when it comes to optimisations but they cannot always afford a cache (port pressure, transitors, ...)

Comment: On linux, you can use `strace` to see what system calls are made during execution of your program.

Comment: OT: regarding: `ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));`  1) `malloc()` returns the type: `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) the parameter is expected to have type: `size_t` however, the variable `n` has type `int`.  The compiler should be telling you about the risk of this implicit conversion.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason for failure to `stderr`

Comment: @user3629249: There's no risk in `n * sizeof(int)` unless `n` could be negative.  That expression has type `size_t` because of promotion rules, and `n` promotes to `size_t` before the multiply.  There is also a prototype for `malloc` so the compiler already knows it has to promote the arg even if you did `4 * n`, although that would be a risk for signed overflow.  Agreed on your other point, don't cast malloc's return value in C.

Comment: @PeterCordes,  Suggest you read the MAN page.  Then enable the warnings for your compiler.  (for `gcc`, use the `-Wconversion` option )  Then the compiler will warn you about the problems I mentioned

Comment: @user3629249: There's a reason it's not enabled as part of `-Wall -Wextra -Wpendantic` (https://godbolt.org/z/kFkPoC): integer promotion is very rarely dangerous.  In this case there's no danger because `n` is a signed positive compile-time constant.  `conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]` isn't a possible danger because we know `n` is a compile-time constant value that's non-negative.

Answer (score 3):

Before the program runs, the operating system and the C runtime setup the necessary values in the CPU registers.

As you've already noted, the intended PC value is set by the operating system (e.g. by the loader) and then the CPU's PC (aka IP) register is set, probably with a "return from interrupt" instruction that both switches to user mode (activating the virtual memory map for that process) along with loading the CPU with the proper PC value (a virtual address).

In addition, the SP register is set somehow: in some systems this will be done similar to the PC during the "return from interrupt", but in other (older) systems the user code sets the SP to a prearranged location.  In either case the SP also holds a virtual memory address.

Usually the first instruction in that runs in the user process is in a routine traditionally called `_start` in a library called `crt0` (C RunTime 0 (aka startup)).  `_start` is usually written in assembly and handles the transition from the operating system to user mode.  As needed `_start` will establish anything else necessary for C code to be called, and then, call `main`.  If `main` returns to `_start`, it will do an `exit` syscall.

The CPU caches (and probably TLBs) will be cold when `_start`'s first instruction gets control.  All addresses in user mode are virtual memory addresses that designate memory within the (virtual) address space of the process.  The processor is running in user mode.  Probably the operating system has preloaded the page holding `_start` (or a least the start of `_start`).  So when the processor performs an instruction fetch from `_start`, it will probably TLB miss, but not page fault, and then cache miss.

The TLB is a set of registers forming a cache in the CPU that support virtual to physical address translations/mappings.  The TLB, when it misses, will be loaded from a structure in the virtual memory mapping for the process, such as the page tables.  Since that first page is preloaded, the attempt to map will succeed, and the TLB will then be filled with the proper mappings from the virtual PC page to the physical page.  However, the L1/L2, etc.. caches are also cold, so the access next causes a cache miss.  The memory system will satisfy the cache miss by filling a cache line at each level.  Finally an instruction word or group of words is provided to the processor, and it begins executing instructions.

If a virtual address for code (by way of the PC) or data (by some dereference) is not present in the TLB, then the processor will consult the page tables, and a miss there can cause a recoverable or non-recoverable page fault.  Recoverable page faults are virtual to physical mappings that are not present in the page tables, because the data is on disc and operating system intervention is required; whereas non-recoverable faults are accesses to virtual memory that are in error, i.e. not allowed as they refer to virtual memory that has not been allocated/authorized by the operating system.

Variable `i` is known to `main` as a stack-relative location.  So, when main wants to write to `i` it will write to memory and an offset from SP, e.g. SP+8 (`i` could also be a register variable, but I digress).  Since the SP is a pointer holding a virtual memory address, `i` then has a virtual address.  That virtual address goes thru the above described steps: TLB mapping from virtual page to physical page, possible page faulting, and then possible cache miss.  Subsequent access will yield TLB hits, and cache hits, so as to run at full speed.  (The operating system will probably also preload some but not all stack pages before running the process.)

A `malloc` operation will use some system calls that ultimately cause additional virtual memory to be added to the process.  (Though as you also note, `malloc` gets more than enough for the current request so the system calls are not done every `malloc`.)  `malloc` will return a virtual memory address, i.e. a pointer in the user mode virtual address space.  For memory just obtained by a system call, the TLB and caches are also probably code, and it is possible that the page is not even loaded yet as well.  In the latter case, a recoverable page fault will happen and the OS will allocate a physical page to use.  If the OS is smart it will know that this is a new data page, and so can fill it with zeros instead of loading it from the paging file.  Then it will set up the page table entries for the proper mapping, and resume the user process, which will probably then TLB miss, fill a TLB entry from the page tables, and then cache miss, and fill cache lines from the physical page.

Comment: The OS also puts data on the user-space stack (or at some known location in the process's virtual address space) before entering user-space.  The x86-64 System V ABI for example (Linux, MacOS, some others) specifies that the stack pointer initially points at `argc`, and `argv[]` and `envp[]` are above it.  (The actual arrays of char*, not just pointers to arrays.)  I think Linux generally works the same way on non-x86 ISAs.

Comment: *(activating the virtual memory map for that process)* On x86 at least, `iret` doesn't modify the page tables.  The OS uses the same page tables as user-space, including some pages that have a bit set that indicates kernel-only.  (on x86, the U/S = user/supervisor).  The kernel maps these same pages as part of every user-space page table.  (In fact probably just pointing a page-directory pointer at the same 2nd/3rd/4th level page tables.)  There's another bit that tells the CPU it can keep this entry in the TLB when changing the top-level page pointer, i.e. a promise that it's mapped the same.

Comment: Fun fact: that U/S bit is what Meltdown bypasses (on Intel), and why the workaround for that is actually *not* leaving the kernel pages mapped when returning to user-space, other than the IDT and kernel entry points.  But the kernel achieves that with a `mov` to CR3; `iret` doesn't do it for you.  See https://wiki.osdev.org/Page_Tables and also [Why in 64bit the virtual address are 4 bits short (48bit long) compared with the physical address (52 bit long)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46509152) for a diagram of page-table nesting.

Comment: For more details on page walks, see [What happens after a L2 TLB miss?](//stackoverflow.com/q/32256250) (for current x86 hardware vs. stuff like MIPS with software TLB-miss handling with a handler provided by the kernel).

Comment: Access to the stack memory for `i` is extremely unlikely to TLB-miss because `_start` was just using the stack before calling `main`.  `main` doesn't use a lot of stack space so it's probably still the same page, so the translation is still hot in the TLB.

Comment: After `malloc` uses `mmap` or `sbrk` to allocate a new page from the OS, it will typically not be "wired" into the hardware page tables at all (so a page-fault on a write will cause the OS to create a new zeroed physical page and wire up the handler), or copy-on-write mapped to a shared physical zero page. (A read fault on a fresh page from the OS typically creates that condition, so you can get TLB misses but L1d cache hits if you aren't careful in doing a microbenchmark.)  But anyway, I've seen "wired" as terminology for being in the HW page tables as well as the kernel's logical memory map.